# Fixed effect counts in modelsummary

Tags: r, modelsummary, fixest

I have a `modelsummary` of three fixed effects regressions like so:

```r
remotes::install_github("lrberge/fixest")
remotes::install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")

library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)

mod1 <- feols(mpg ~ hp | cyl, data = mtcars)
mod2 <- feols(mpg ~ wt | cyl, data = mtcars)
mod3 <- feols(mpg ~ drat | cyl, data = mtcars)

modelsummary(list(mod1, mod2, mod3), output = "markdown")
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 | Model 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hp | -0.024 |  |  |
|  | (0.015) |  |  |
| wt |  | -3.206 |  |
|  |  | (1.188) |  |
| drat |  |  | 1.793 |
|  |  |  | (1.564) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 | 32 |
| R2 | 0.754 | 0.837 | 0.745 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.727 | 0.820 | 0.718 |
| R2 Within | 0.080 | 0.392 | 0.048 |
| R2 Within Adj. | 0.047 | 0.371 | 0.014 |
| AIC | 167.9 | 154.6 | 169.0 |
| BIC | 173.8 | 160.5 | 174.9 |
| RMSE | 2.94 | 2.39 | 2.99 |
| Std.Errors | by: cyl | by: cyl | by: cyl |
| FE: cyl | X | X | X |

**Instead of having the table show merely whether certain fixed effects were present, is it possible to show the number of fixed effects that were estimated instead?**

The raw models do contain this information:

```r
> mod1
OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: mpg
Observations: 32 
Fixed-effects: cyl: 3
Standard-errors: Clustered (cyl) 
    Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|) 
hp -0.024039   0.015344 -1.56664  0.25771 
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 2.94304     Adj. R2: 0.727485
                Within R2: 0.07998
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you’ll need to define a `glance_custom.fixest()` method. See this section of the docs for detailed instructions and many examples:

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#customizing-existing-models-part-i

And here’s an example with `fixest`:

```r
library(fixest)
library(tibble)
library(modelsummary)

models <- list(
    feols(mpg ~ hp | cyl, data = mtcars),
    feols(mpg ~ hp | am, data = mtcars),
    feols(mpg ~ hp | cyl + am, data = mtcars)
)

glance_custom.fixest <- function(x, ...) {
    tibble::tibble(`# FE` = paste(x$fixef_sizes, collapse = " + "))
}

modelsummary(models, gof_map = c("nobs", "# FE"))
```

|  | (1) | (2) | (3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hp | -0.024 | -0.059 | -0.044 |
|  | (0.015) | (0.000) | (0.016) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 | 32 |
| # FE | 3 | 2 | 3 + 2 |

Comment: Oh excellent! Any way I can retain one row for each separate fixed effect, with the number of levels for each FE in the cell bodies?

Comment: Well, you can do whatever you want by changing the `glance_custom.fixest` function and adding new columns to the output data frame, but you'll have to look at the structure of the `fixest` object to identify exactly the info you want/need: `str(model)`